# How can I add a ui text automatic with a space at the bottom of an Image to avoid overlap by script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Canvas > Panel.
Under the Panel there is a Image.
Under the Image there is another Image and a Text both are childs of the first Image :

The Loading... is at Y position -81 the vica image position on Y is at 0
I have some other images with texts like that. Some of the texts at position -34 or -20 or -40 on Y.
All the vicas images at Y position 0 (or 0.3)

My question is if there is a way to position or better to create the ui text and then position is automatic under the vica/s images with some space without overlap ? Instead dragging on my own each text to find the right space.

[image: vice image and ui text]

Comment: Have you tried using the [vertical layout group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Vertical Layout Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html), which is a bit tricky to work with, but it can simplify your work in a lot of ways.

In your specific example, you could have a parent GameObject, with the VerticalLayoutGroup component, and the Image and Text GameObjects as its children. You could then use the LayoutGroup to handle the spacing between the two children.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this would be the result:

[image]

In case you need more advanced control over the arrangement and size of UI elements, there are many components that are worth looking into, and you can find them [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-UIAutoLayout.html).